# DJANGO Supplement to the data list via an intermediate table

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have an intermediate models connection

Simplified:

```
class Person(models.Model):
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      etc...
                
class Company(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
      etc...
        
class CompanyEnrollment(models.Model):
      person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      company_position = 
      models.ForeignKey(CompanyPosition,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      etc...
      
      class Meta:
            unique_together = [['person', 'company']]
    
class CompanyPosition(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

I want to create the following array:

```
datas = Person.objects.All(...{All elements of Person model supplemented with CompanyPosition_name}...)
```

There is a case where a person does not have a company_name association
Is it possible to solve this with a query?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an [explicit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) `through` model for your many-to-many relationship, you could use this to only get or exclude based on the entries of this table, using an [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) clause:

```py
enrollments = CompanyEnrollment.objects.filter(person_id=OuterRef('pk'))
enrolled_persons = Person.objects.filter(Exists(enrollments))
unenrolled_persons = Person.objects.filter(~Exists(enrollments))
```

If you don't have an explicit intermediate table, then it's has been generated by Django directly. You should be able to use it by referring to it with `Person.enrollments.through` instead of `CompanyEnrollment`.

Since you did not detailed much the CompanyEnrollment table, I assumed you're in the second case.

Comment: Thx! I have an intermediate table (CompanyEnrollment), it contains other data but it is not relevant now.
I want to list all Person data, the task is to show company_name in the list if it is assigned

Comment: mmh I might have misunderstood something. Is the FK to person a OneToOneField, or a ForeignKey? Because if it's the latter, a person could potentially have multiple company names

Comment: `code`
class CompanyEnrollment(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: Then there is a mismatch between the requirement implied by the question (a person can be in multiple companies according to the models, but you question imply that the person will be in a single company at most). By the way, it would be better to edit your question to add the class code in a properly formatted way :)

Comment: unique_together = [['person', 'company']] - protects multiple connections. I edited the post

Comment: Well, the `unique_together` constraint will prevent Person A to be enrolled multiple times in Company B, but he will still be able to be enrolled in both Company B and Company C at the same time

Comment: Legitimate! And so I want to use it

Comment: Alright, then I'm not sure how the company names should be represented in the end query result in case there are multiple enrollments for a single person, should they be concatenated?

Comment: So, I would need Person data, supplemented with which companies it is associated with (CompanyPosition__name). And because of the HTML template, it would be better to have a Person dictionary that I can write out.

Comment: I see, thing is the Django ORM will not be able to spit out a nested dictionary out of the blue. Maybe the best workaround would be to fetch the Person with all the needed data in one go (with `prefetch_related` and `select_related`) and build the dictionary as wanted?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution in my opinion, but it works for now, with little data. I think this is a slow solution for a lot of data.

views.py I will compile the two necessary dictionaries

```
 datas = Person.objects.all().order_by('last_name', 'first_name')
 companys = CompanyEnrollment.objects.all()
```

Use Paginator

```
p = Paginator(Person.objects.all(), 20)
page = request.GET.get('page')
pig = p.get_page(page)
pages = "p" * pig.paginator.num_pages
```

Render HTML:

```
context = {
        "datas": datas,
        "pig": pig,
        "pages": pages,
        "companys": companys,

    }
    return render(request, "XY.html", context)
```

HTML template:

```
{% for datas in pig %}
   {{datas.first_name}} {{datas.last_name}}
     {% for company in companys  %} 
          {% if datas == company.person %}
               {{company.company.name}} <br>
          {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

not the most beautiful, but it works ... I would still accept a more elegant solution.

Comment: I think you can spare quite some manual matching by declaring a ManyToManyField on your person model (that uses `CompanyEnrollment` as a through model). This would not change your DB structure, but it would allow you to do `{% for company in datas.companies.all %}` in your template rendering, without need for extra comparison

Comment: Also, making `Person.objects.all().prefetch_related('companies')` would make it DB performances friendly